# Error message breaks layout when displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-form-validator

I have the following field on my page

[image]

Which is constructed with the following HTML

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px" class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Choose a username (max 25)", Maxlength = "25", autocomplete = "off" })
</div>
```

pretty basic stuff, I currently have jquery form validation embedded into my application which looks like this:

I have removed all the fields besides this one.

```
 $('#registrationForm').validate({
    rules: {
        "Username": "required",

    },
    messages: {
        "Username": "Please enter your chosen Username",

    }
});
```

When I leave the field blank and press submit it looks like this

[image]

As you can see the user glyphicon height has been increased to cater for the error message.

The rendered HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
 <span class="input-group-addon">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
 </span>
<input id="Username" class="form-control" type="text" value="" placeholder="Choose a username (max 25)" name="Username" data-val-required="The Username field is required." data-val="true" autocomplete="off" maxlength="25">
</div>
```

Can anyone suggest why this might be happening?

**Update**

This is what is render when the error message is displayed

```
<div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
 <span class="input-group-addon">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
 </span>
<input id="Username" class="form-control error" type="text" value="" placeholder="Choose a username (max 25)" name="Username" data-val-required="The Username field is required." data-val="true" autocomplete="off" maxlength="25">
<label class="error" for="Username">Please enter your chosen Username</label>
</div>
```

[image]

** Update after adding additional styles to .Error class **

[image]

Comment: Can you inspect element and show the `<span>` that gets generated?

Answer (score 0):

There's an extra `<span>` that gets generated when you do this! I guess it should be `.error`. Just give a `position: absolute;` to it.

```
.error {position: absolute; right: 0; width: 100%; bottom: -1em;}
```

Or just take the error text out of the `.input-group`:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px" class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
</div>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Choose a username (max 25)", Maxlength = "25", autocomplete = "off" })
```

Comment: I added the position absolute but the error message appeared on the same line as the textbox but at the end, and it was all squashed up (couldn't read it).  If I use the HTML you have supplied then the glyphicon user is no longer next to the box, instead it appears on top. Which is not what I want

Comment: @ScottAtkinson Please update the generated HTML by inspecting the element there. We can move it forward easily. Remember, you need to use only one, either position absolute or the HTML outside the div.

Comment: I have updated the style .error to have the position of absolute

Comment: Good. As expected. What happens when you give absolute? Post a screenshot!

Comment: The error message appears to the right hand side of the textbox but its all squashed and un-readable.

Comment: I've added a screen shot, will try your updated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80373/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-scott-atkinson).

Comment: I've added the styles your suggested, I have also updated the question with the latest picture after applying the styles

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style to the error message

```
position : absolute
```